# jQuery Select Individual Checkbox in Group

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simply select one individual checkbox in a group of boxes and can't figure it out.

Here is the code that creates my checkbox group dynamically. I need to be able to loop through and select individual boxes that were checked previously by the user:

```
<?php
    //Display all "cheese" options in a checkbox group
    foreach($_SESSION['ingr_cheese'] as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"cheesebox\" style=\"float:left; width:175px; margin-bottom:7px;\">";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cheese1\" class=\"cheeseCheck\" value=\"".$key."\">&nbsp;<label for=\"cheese1\">".$value['cheese']."</label></br>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Once I figure out how to check just one I can figure out the loop. Here is the jQuery code I'm trying to select just the checkbox with index value "1":

```
$("#cheese1:checkbox:eq('1')").attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: `id`s are meant to be unique people. Why is it that so many of you can't figure out what is **unique identification**

Comment: I just realized I left the id in there, let me remove it. I do have the class in there.

Comment: Also, just a quick UI tip: wrap your **labels** -around- your checkbox, it will improve clickability (since lots of people click on the words next to it, than just the checkbox itself). Example: `<label><input type="checkbox" /> Blah blah</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the checked attribute instead of the selected attribute and select the checkboxes this way instead of using the `:checked` selector.  For jQuery 1.6 and above do:

```
$('div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]').eq(1).prop('checked', true);
```

For jQuery < 1.6 do:

```
$('div.cheesebox input[type=checkbox]').eq(1).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: But I'm trying to re-check boxes that were checked in the past by a user when they return to the page. So they originally checked boxes 1, 3, 5. How do I make sure those boxes are checked when they return to the page?

Comment: @XanderNGCC Sorry about that. I read your question too quickly.  I updated the answer.

Comment: that worked great, thanks! I was really struggling to get that one figured out. :)